# Biqquery: Error - Some rows belong to different partitions rather than destination partition

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I have the following partitions in my table partitioned by 'DATE'

```
Row partition_id

1   20210222

2   20210223
```

I am trying to overwrite one of these partitions '20210222' by using Bigquery python API

My tablename is `table_name$20210222` and I am using `WRITE_TRUNCATE` as the write-disposition but I am getting the following error:

```
google.api_core.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Some rows belong to different partitions
      rather than destination partition 20210222
```

I want to be able to overwrite just one of these partitions through my python code. It works fine for `WRITE_APPEND` and `WRITE_TRUNCATE` but `WRITE_APPEND` adds duplication and `WRITE_TRUNCATE` deletes the previous table and only adds new data. I want to replace data for an existing partition.

Comment: Since you want to overwrite a specific partition `WRITE_TRUNCATE` should work when pointed to the destination partition like `table_name$20210222`. If the field that the table is partitioned by is TIMESTAMP type check if the timezone is UTC. BigQuery stores every timestamp in UTC, so if you have your data in a different one, some entries of the same day might belong to different partitions when converted to UTC.

Comment: Thanks so much @itroulli. That was the issue. I reset the column to UTC and the date field as well and it worked like a charm.

Comment: Happy that I helped! I've posted my suggestion as an answer, please accept (and upvote) it so other users that have the same issue can find it easily.

Comment: Thanks. I upvoted but it won't show up because my reputation is low.

Comment: Thanks! The important part though is to accept it so your question is shown as answered :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BigQuery converts and stores all `TIMESTAMP` values in the UTC timezone. So, if you have a partitioned by `DAY` table and you try to insert a timestamp in a different timezone than UTC, it will be first converted to UTC and then stored in the relevant partition.

In your case, it seems that you had a value like `2020-12-25 00:30:00 CET` which when converted to UTC upon storing is `2020-12-24 23:30:00 UTC` so it belongs to a different partition than other values from the same day (in your timezone).

That leads to the error that you encountered because you are trying to overwrite a specific partition and some of the entries that you are trying to insert belong to a different one.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try to use the MERGE statement directly to overwrite data on that particular partition as below.

```
MERGE INTO `table` AS INTERNAL_DEST
USING (
 SELECT * FROM data_to_overwrite
) AS INTERNAL_SOURCE
ON FALSE

when not matched by source
    and INTERNAL_DEST.partition_id BETWEEN 20210222 AND 20210222 
          -- the range of the partitions to be overwritten
    then delete

when not matched then insert ROW
```

UPDATE for additional notes and caveat.

I would say this is the only feasible way that I know about to update data like this.  wrapping this query within python code and calling the python code for overwriting historical data.

Please note that overwrite historical data is against BQ best practice for loading data. It could be used sparely for batch updating data. and it shall never be used as a transactional update operation like what we do in a transactional database.

This is considered a DML operation, which has a much lower quota comparing to other data loading approaches. See this post for details about the difference between BQ loading strategies. [BigQuery: too many table dml insert operations for this table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66402422/bigquery-too-many-table-dml-insert-operations-for-this-table/66406248#66406248)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Actually, I have been using the bigquery API with python and have most of the job set including loading data into the table based on partitions and therefore, I wanted to configure this through airflow using the python operator and was trying to get it to work programmatically with my code. Would you say that this is the only way - wrapping this query within python code and calling this job for overwriting historical data?

Comment: yes, I would say this is the only feasible way that I know about.  wrapping this query within python code and calling this job for overwriting historical data. Please note that overwrite historical data is against BQ best practice, and this is consider a DML operation, which has much lower quota comparing to other data loading approach.